# Rest Service not responding?

Tags: rest

I have the following code for a rest client to access the rest service:

```
@Override
    public String putDeal(String deal) throws RestException {
        String responseStr = null;
        String restUrl = RestPropertyUtil.getRestUrl();
        STATIC_LOGGER.info("REST restUrl: " + restUrl);
        if (null != deal) {

            HttpEntity<Object> request = new HttpEntity<Object>(deal.getBytes(Charset.forName(UTF8)), getHttpHeaders(false));

            ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(restUrl, HttpMethod.PUT, request, String.class);
            if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
                responseStr = response.getBody();
            } else {
                STATIC_LOGGER.error("RestException: Request could not be completed successfully.", response.getHeaders().toString());
                throw new RestException("RestException: Request could not be completed successfully.");
            }
        }
        return responseStr;
    }
```

Out of 50 Rest requests (Over a period of 12 hrs, each request takes around min 5 sec to max 1 minute to complete), 45 returned from the rest server and remaining 5 never responded.

When i asked the Rest Service developer, he confirmed those 5 requests came to their server (verified from the Log at the start of the service method) but he doesn't see coming out of their service (at the end of the service method) and hence no response came to the rest client.

Do you think this needs to be investigated by the rest service team or is there anything i can do from the rest client's point of view (like implement using HttpClient along with RestTemplate for connection pooling) which could resolve this issue?

FYI: when ever i try this service from the rest client plugin in Firefox, it always gets a response. So i am thinking this could be related to the rest client code.

Comment: If it always seems to work in a browser or when using another tool then perhaps the issue is in your http client in your code.  Does the request take a long time usually?  If so, perhaps you could set your "Timeout" property on the http client in code to something higher.  If the client times out when it is making a request it will typically behave as you are describing.